# Are using modules in VB.NET considered bad practice?

Tags: .net, vb.net, module

During the design of a new application I was wondering if using a module with properties is considered to be a bad practice.

Some example code:

```
Module modSettings

   public property Setting1 as string

   public property DatabaseObject as IDatabaseObject

End Module
```

The code above is just an example to emphasize my question. In the past, this structure was used a lot in VB6. In the past I used it as well in my .NET projects.

But nowadays with buzzwords like Dependency Injection, Testability and Separation of Concerns the above structure smells bad. I can't really describe why, but it just feels wrong. I must admit I'm not very familiar with the keywords above, yet.

So I'm wondering whether the above code really **is** a bad practice. If so, what would you use a `Module` for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Centro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265134/net-module-bad-practice/6265414#6265414) is right that a Module (or a NotInheritable Class with Shared members) is the ***closest* equivalent to a C# static class**. So technically, nothing is wrong with it as it's just one of VB's ways of creating this type of class. For example, you cannot say `Public Shared Class Settings` in VB as you cannot put the `Shared` keyword on a class.

On its own I wouldn't call it bad practice if a specific circumstance calls for a Module, but otherwise a Module (or other static class equivalents) likely is not the design choice you want for having loosely coupled, testable code. Additionally, while a NotInheritable Class with Shared members is more descriptive than just saying Module, there is at least one circumstance where a Module must be used instead.

**When would you need to use Modules in VB.Net? If you want to take advantage of [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx), then it's your only option** since as mentioned, you cannot create a shared (static) class in VB.Net, neither can you use extensions on NotInheritable Classes. You must use a module as follows:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function Remove( _
                        ByVal input As String, _
                        ByVal subStrings As String()) As String
        Return String.Join("", input.Split(subStrings, StringSplitOptions.None)).Trim()
    End Function
End Module
```

In C# you can't use modules and must use static classes as follows:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public string Remove(this string input, string[] subStrings)
    {
        return string.Join("", input.Split(subStrings, StringSplitOptions.None)).Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"sealed static class"_ is not possible in C# since a static class in C# is sealed by default, so IMO _"equivalent to a C# static class"_ sounds more precise.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation! So basically you'd only use Modules (in VB.NET) for extension methods?

Comment: @Rhapsody, unless there is something else out there that requires using modules (and I can't think of any), then yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword *Module* in VB.NET came from VB 6. Actually it is compiled as *NotInheritable Class* with making all members static, in C# it is as *sealed class* with static members.

I think it is a bad practice since it is not quite clear that it is actually a class with static members.

Comment: Unclear? Only until you read the documentation. There's no other way to create a static class in VB.Net.

Comment: @MarkJ Yes, there's no way to simply (without simulation via `NotInheritable Class`) create a static class in VB.NET. Anyway it would be better to have in VB.NET something like `Shared Class` than `Module` to make it clear it's a class, though static.

Comment: +1 as I agree that NotInheritable Class is preferable to Module for descriptiveness, except of course for situations where a Module is your only option as exemplified in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with properties.  In fact, to implement binding you need properties and to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  I think I would prefer classes over modules though, but I'm a C# guy mainly.

Comment: But you've got Modules as well in C# :-) My question is more about the usage of a Module for application-wide objects/properties.

Comment: In C# module is a shortcut to a sealed class with all static members.  I would never use the Module key word in C# as that would be a hack way of doing things.  In VB.Net, Module is a viable option though I would do this with class implementation.

Comment: There is no `module` keyword in C#, at least per the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to do this I must admit I have never seen it done in practise. In my opinion it is easier to read in a class as this declaration is explicit and using a class allows you to convert to a class later on if the need arises. So I can't think of any reason why you would want to do this over a class with a shared member

Comment: Because, like in the example, the DatabaseObject is now a single instance which can be used in any part of the application.